# This is my very first developer position and I'd like to know what I should expect and what I should be doing to prepare

Tags: career-development, software-development, new-hires, entry-level

I'm very excited about a new job offer I've just accepted as an entry level developer. I am set to start in June 2021 so I have a good chunk of time until then. This is my very first developer position and I'd like to know what I should expect and what I should be doing to prepare.

The position is in the auto industry and will likely be writing software for the future of EVs (Electric Vehicles/Autonomous Driving) if that matters at all.

Comment: you've been hired for a start in more than 6 months? Wow that's far away! Congratulations anyway. Now why do you think we could have any idea about what you should expect in this position? Better ask them! It will also be appreciated that you already invest some personal time learning before joining.

Comment: @LaurentS. that would make for a good answer!

Comment: Questions on stack exchange sites must be *specific* and *specifically answerable*.  Broad questions seeking an open-ended laundry list of answers do not fit here.

Answer (score 8):

> This is my very first developer position and I'd like to know what I should expect and what I should be doing to prepare.

I suggest you **write them an email where you politely ask them for such things that you want to know**. Who better than them (your future employer) to know what you should be preparing or getting up to speed for your upcoming job.

A phrasing I may suggest would be (feel free to adapt as you seem fit):

> Hello [company or contact name],
>
> I am grateful for the offer and excited to get started on the role. In preparation for it, I would like to know if there is anything you suggest I do, read, or prepare in order to get up to speed for the tasks I will be having.
>
> Thank you,
>
> aj0320

Answer (score 1):

> This is my very first developer position and I'd like to know what I should expect and what I should be doing to prepare.

Unless you're a student finishing your degree in the spring, it's unusual for a company to offer a position 7+ months before the start date. It might help us understand your situation if you'd explain more about that.

As this is an entry-level position presumably with a large corporation, it's a good bet that the company will train you on the specific tools and processes that you'll be using. It might not hurt to ask if there's anything you can or should bone up on in preparation for starting, but trust that they know what they're doing when it comes to hiring and training new people and try not to worry about it too much. Instead, focus on what's in front of you right now. If you're still in school, concentrate on finishing this semester well and learning as much as you can in the spring.